# How to implement a ContentObserver in a fragment using CursorAdapter and LoaderCallbacks?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader, contentobserver

I am using a `CursorAdapter` in a `ListFragment` to load and display a list of comments.

```
public class CommentsFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    protected Activity mActivity;
    protected CursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mActivity = getActivity();
        mAdapter = new CommentsCursorAdapter(mActivity, null, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        mActivity.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CustomContract.Comments.CONTENT_URI, false, new CommentsObserver());
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle extras) {
        Uri uri = CustomContract.Comments.CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(mActivity, uri, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    protected class CommentsObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public CommentsObserver() {
            super(new Handler());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            // TODO Trigger a reload.
        }

    }
}
```

In the associated ContentProvider I added `notifyChange()` for the *insert* action.

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case COMMENTS: {
            long id = db.insert(DatabaseProperties.TABLE_NAME_COMMENTS, null, values);
            Uri itemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
            // FIXME Which one is right?
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(itemUri, null);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            return itemUri;
        }
        default: {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it okay to pass `null` to `notifyChange()` as the observer parameter? If not, what object am I supposed to pass here?
2. Should I pass the `uri` or the `itemUri` in `notifyChange()`? Why?
3. What method do I have to call in `CommentsObserver#onChange()` to update the list of comments?
4. Is there no interface I could implement with the `ListFragment` instead of the inner class instance of `ContentObserver`?
5. I simply instantiate a `new Handler()` in the constructor of `CommentsObserver`. This seems not correct to me - please explain.

Comment: ok, i did it ... you can try my library http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com ... yes, it's intended to use it with MSFT ... but it can also works without it ... you can remove all sync code and then you will have library for easy runtime ContentProvider generator from Annotations :)

Comment: I will have a look at it. Thank you, again.

Comment: check [this](http://selvin.pl/AutoContent.zip) ... i've stripped sync code and made sample project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SqlCursor` already have internal `ContentObserver` and  since you're using this `Cursor` implementation there is no need for own `ContentObserver` implementation.

For easy use you can add:

```
class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider{
  //rest implementation goes here
  @Override
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    //check uri, select table name based on uri, etc ...
    cursor = db.query(/*.....*/);
    //add this line:
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    //before you return cursor
    return cursor;
  }
  @Override
  public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
     /* ... */
       //you can notify only "dir" uri and is should be enough
       getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
       return itemUri;
     /* ... */
  }
  //rest of implementation goes here
}
```

after this, `CursorLoader` internal implementation will take care of reloading/refreshing data ...

Comment: I am having a similar problem and I've implemented my ListFragment without a ContentObserver and my ListView doesn't update.

Currently when the fragment is created it starts and intent service to query the server for updated data while showing the old data from the local SQLLite DB. When retrieved it updates the local DB and notifies the change. 

In my first implementation with the ContentObserver onChange fires and I invoke notifyDataSetChanged on the SimpleCursorAdapter.

I tried the above design too and still doesn't update. When I recreate the activity and fragment it shows the new data.

Comment: are you using CursorLoader? and do you use update method of CP in your retrive from cloud code?

Comment: I am using cursor loader and in my service connecting to the cloud it does an insert, "getContentResolver().insert(Uri.withAppendedPath(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, "table name"), values);" and the execution of that insertsWithOnConflict based on a unique filed and does an update. So typically it does an update.

Comment: are you sure that uris are the same (in insert and in "select"(`new CursorLoader(..., uri, ...)` and `getContentResolver().insert(uri,...)`), next did you add those line which i mention in my answer (`notifyChange` in insert/update and `setNotificationUri` in select) ...for checking if "autorefresh" mechanism works, add button/menu with code `getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` to your ListFragment  ... i'm pretty sure that it should works ... anyway check code from my second comment to question

Comment: after I double checked the URIs the notification to the URI on the CP different. Notifying after insert in the service solved my problem. Thanks for the clues!